# URL in SQL 2016 to return XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have my sql returning information and building a url.

```
SELECT Address,Address2,'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&origins='+Address+'&destinations='+Address2+'&key=xxx' URL

FROM table
```

And if I take the URL that's created above and copy it into a browser the needed XML appears in the screen. But how can I have the XML within SQL so I can parse only specific data such as travel time?

So now I have the following code that provides me with the time:

```
DECLARE @Address0 varchar(100) =null
DECLARE @Address1 varchar(100)=null

SET @Address0 = 'xxx'
SET @Address1 = 'yyy'

Declare @Object as Int;
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);
Declare @serviceUrl as varchar(500)
  set @serviceUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&origins=' +@Address0+
   '&destinations=' +@Address1 +'&key=keyfromgoogle'
Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
                @serviceUrl, --Your Web Service Url (invoked)
                 'false'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

Declare @Response as XML

SET @Response = CAST(@ResponseText AS XML);
   Declare @Time as varchar(20)
   Begin
      set @Time=@Response.value('(DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/duration/text)[1]', 'varchar(20)') 
   End
  select 
  @Time as Time
```

So I'm thinking I create a temp table to hold my addresses and then a cursor to run through and add the time to each row of the temp table?

Comment: If you want to parse it within SQL Server you will need to import the XML into a table or variable.  How you do that is up to you based on your needs for processing the XML.  There are quite a few options too choose from, but there's not enough information here to suggest the best route for you to take.

Comment: Simply storing the URL in a database table and selecting from that table will not actually invoke any sort of REST API call to that URL and retrieve/download the response.   As squillman mentioned, you have to code for it.   You'll need to create a SSIS package with probably script task to make the call and retrieve the response, or an external application or you could explore using CURL extensions like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/04/17/calling-http-endpoints-in-t-sql-using-curl-extension/ .